# jquery ajax upload form serialize with Authorization header

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a Web Api which uses a custom AuthorizationFilterAttribute which checks the Headers of the request for a valid apikey in the Authorization header.

I have this working for GET and POST requests.
When posting a form I am using jQuery to serialize the form and than post it. 
The jQuery code looks like this:

```
var postURL = "@localPostUrl";
var serializedForm = $('form').serialize();
$('input#submitButton').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: postURL,
        type: 'post',
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'blaBLA'
        },                
        dataType: 'json',
        data: serializedForm,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

So when clicking the button with id submitButton on the form it will serialize the form content and than post it together with an Authorization token in the headers.

Hoever, in one form I also need to upload a file when posting. If I check the request.Files on the Web Api, it is just empty so I guess the file is not posted.

I posted the form with jQuery because I need to send the authentication token in the Headers and sending it with a submit button does not work.

So now I am facing a deadlock. I need to use jQuery to send the authentication token, but I also need to upload a file and they don't work together.

Has anyone solved this problem already?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/2918/how-to-set-a-request-header-in-a-jquery-ajax-call.aspx

Comment: @zer02 The link you gave does what I already did. So it adds a header before sending the request. This is no problem. The problem is that the file is not serialized/uploaded when posting the form with jQuery.